How does PCIe work?
I have gotten very confused with how PCIe works. I read that PCIe is a memory mapped protocol.  That is, if the GPU wants to write to the CPU it will access the DDR memory located on the motherboard and write to it directly - and the CPU when ever it would like will read that section from memory.
When the GPU is allowed to overwrite the same addresses and when to stop writing so it will not get overflow
and if the information was not read by the CPU, how can it choose other address to write to?
Why does the GPU also act as root complex with its own memory? What happens then? Who access how memory at which condition?
Is the configuration space located at the shared DDR memory, or is it local on the endpoint?

Memory mapping just means that the CPU in the system can access peripherals using addresses. These address ranges are configured by the PCIe root complex in the CPU. If the CPU wants to write to an endpoint device it uses these virtual memory mapped addresses and the root complex takes care of communication with the endpoint devices.
The GPU has its own memory spaces along with some protocol defined configuration registers within it. Initially after power on, it is not allowed to send anything to the system RAM - a configuration register prevents it from doing so.
Once and endpoint (i.e. the GPU) is enumerated and the various software drivers are loaded by the operating system, the operating system is able to talk to the device and send data to its internal memory spaces. The format of that memory and what it is used for is entirely manufacturer defined.
Typically every interaction is controlled by the system CPU. For sending small amounts of data (e.g. a few commands) the CPU can just write to it's one PCIe controller and ask for the data to be sent word by word. No need for system RAM to be involved. It can also read small amounts of data word by word from the GPU. Again this just involves the CPU and it's PCIe controller, no system RAM. There are also interrupts defined within the PCIe spec to allow the endpoint to notify the system CPU that something has happened or needs to be checked (e.g. to say that it is ready to accept or send data).
For large amounts of data this is very inefficient. So instead endpoint devices can optionally implement DMA controllers in the PCI controller logic. The OS can enable configuration settings to allow the endpoint to be a bus master - this gives it permission to perform it's own read and write requests autonomously. The software drivers can then instruct the endpoint to transfer the data themselves.
Bus mastering and DMA controllers are implementation specific - how they work is entirely defined by the manufacturer. However generally speaking the are entirely controlled by the driver software - all of the coordination of transfers is done by wthe CPU writing to implementation defined memory addresses in the endpoint, along with interrupts from the endpoint to the CPU to tell it to check status memory registers.

To give a perspective, in the  FPGA device for a system I designed, we use the following approch for DMA control:

The application provides a memory buffer to the driver, which is converted by the driver to a scatter gather list - this is basically just a list of addresses and lengths for each part of the buffer within system RAM.
The list is formatted and placed in a preallocated region of system memory.
The FPGA is instructed to transfer the data from the system memory to memory within the FPGA using a DMA engine. It basically sends read requests to the system PCIe controller to read from the correct place in system RAM. The data received is then used to program a second DMA controller.
The second DMA controller then uses the information about the memory space tor transfer large amounts of data either too or from the applications memory buffer.
The FPGA then reports back to the driver using an interrupt to tell it that the transfer is complete.
The driver can then tell the application that the transfer is finished and ready for other transfers.



I read that PCIe is memory mapped protocol ie if the GPU wants to write to the CPU it will access the DDR memory located on the mother board

You don't write to the CPU. The CPU is not memory. You might want to copy stuff to the main memory, indeed, and all DMA-capable devices can do that.
But that's not what "memory mapped" means. "Memory mapped" means that to interact with the device, you as software running on the system just modify memory addresses, which aren't backed by RAM, but by functionality of the card.
So, please be careful with terminology! Different words mean different things; the problem with abuse of terminology goes on:

When the GPU is allowed to overwrite the same addresses and when to stop writing so it will not get overflow?

This sentence makes no sense. An overflow is a concept from a completely different category.
If the system (usually, through a so-called IOMMU, an input/output memory management unit) prohibits a device to write to a specific address, that's basically a hardware fault to the device.

and if the information was not read by the CPU how can it choose other address to write to?

I'll have to take several guesses on what you mean here, but my intuition is that you want to know:

If the CPU accesses the GPU functionality via addresses, and the GPU can use main memory, how do we make sure these addresses don't clash?

So, first of all, the physical memory and the memory-mapped devices are on different address ranges. They don't overlap.
The question "how does a PCIe device know that the host has consumed something that it wrote to RAM using DMA?" is: it doesn't by itself. You need to write a driver that tells the device what has been read. You can do that in many different ways. In a typical solution, there's a queue on both the host memory side, and on the PCIe device.
These queues hold buffer descriptors, typically simply addresses of memory ranges and their length.
The device takes the tip of its queue (removing it from the queue), looks at the address in that descriptor, issues a DMA command to put data on that address, and when that's done, puts the descriptor into the back of the host-side queue, with the information how long the data was and the address.
The host side then takes the tip of its queue, finds the new descriptor, does whatever it wants to do with the data, and when it's done, puts the descriptor into the back of the queue of the device.

Thankyou for the answer, can you please explain " which aren't backed by RAM, but by functionality of the card."

not much to explain there. These things look exactly the same as memory addresses, but when you read from them or write to them, the data doesn't go to RAM, but to the card.
